# streaming my desktop to youtube using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

There are tutorials out there on how to stream to youtube using ffmpeg, and I have that part of the code done.
However, I do not know how to stream the desktop in ffmpeg. The tutorials online only show usage of web cams. Anyway, What software do I use to capture the screen and stream using ffmpeg.
Can I do this natively in ffmpeg. If so, how?

what I have so far is

```
 ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ab 128k -g 40 -strict experimental -f flv -r 30 rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$1
```

where the `$1` is a command line param.

Comment: Which OS? ffmpeg has grabber devices for Win, Mac, OSX

Comment: linux, arm linux. Im trying to run it on my Raspberry pi.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide the necessary information required to answer your question